# (ROBLOX) Dont add gui when other player join

Tags: lua, roblox

I would explain better here, I'm doing a role game and I do ranks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI1KQ.png)

But if somebody another joins then the text over the head will Destroy and to another player spawn the GUI.

The script:

```
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local Tag = ServerStorage.Tag

local CloneTag = Tag:Clone()


local NameTag = CloneTag.NameTag
local RankTag = CloneTag.RankTag
local VIPTag = CloneTag.VIPTag

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)   
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
        CloneTag.Parent = char.Head
        
        if player:IsInGroup(14472135) then
            if player:GetRankInGroup(14472135) == 1 then
                NameTag.Text = player.Name
                RankTag.Text = "Trainee"

            elseif player:GetRankInGroup(14472135) == 2 then
                NameTag.Text = player.Name
                RankTag.Text = "Police" 

            elseif player:GetRankInGroup(14472135) == 3 then
                NameTag.Text = player.Name
                RankTag.Text = "Specialist" 

            elseif player:GetRankInGroup(14472135) == 4 then
                NameTag.Text = player.Name
                RankTag.Text = "Sergeant"   

            elseif player:GetRankInGroup(14472135) == 252 then 
                NameTag.Text = player.Name
                RankTag.Text = "Corporal"   

            elseif player:GetRankInGroup(14472135) == 253 then
                NameTag.Text = player.Name
                RankTag.Text = "Major"  

            elseif player:GetRankInGroup(14472135) == 254 then
                NameTag.Text = player.Name
                RankTag.Text = "Lieutenant"
                VIPTag.Visible = true

            elseif player:GetRankInGroup(14472135) == 255 then
                NameTag.Text = player.Name
                RankTag.Text = "Colonel"    
                VIPTag.Visible = true
            end

        else
            NameTag.Text = player.Name
            RankTag.Text = "Immigrant"
        end
    end)
end)
```

Any Suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: I remember seeing this code somewhere and someone recommended the replacement of this terrifying `if`-`elseif` chain with an elegant table structure. Is this the second time you're asking this? **Anyway**, you're doing the cloning at the top, when the *script* starts running. You want to do it when the *player* gets a character. Therefore there is only a single GUI and it is shared, so it teleports between players. Clone `CloseTag` when `CharacterAdded` fires, not when the script starts. Make sure to move the related variables too, so they index something that exists.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment, I take this script from a tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnV47TIKrrs) how can i say clone cloneTag when CharacterAdded? Have i to do a bool in the characterAdded? or something so?
Thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but I would not recommend you to watch that channel, judging by the video. There aren't many good video resources about Roblox scripting, and this tutorial is probably made by someone inexperienced. PascalCase (in languages like Lua), use of slangs ("u" instead of "you") and long `if`-`elseif`-`else` chains are signs of inexperienced tutorial creators. When you have to watch a seemingly inexperienced creator's video, take it with a grain of salt and do additional research.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer,sorry but I don't really understand what you mean, but that is what I understand: I should not use elseif or else and I have to change elseif. Can you show me a small example of what you mean I should not use elseif-else? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you simply move the variables so that the cloning is done when a character spawns. There are also ways to make this code better. (1) You can use a table to specify each rank's text, which will shorten it. You can use another table (or the same table with more detailed table values) to store the visibility of the VIP tag. (2) You also don't need to do `NameTag.Text = player.Name` in every `if`-`elseif` body, you can move it out of the `if` so that it will always happen.

I can show a quick example of fix #1:

```lua
local ranks = {
    [1] = "Trainee",
    [2] = "Police",
    [3] = "Specialist",
    --...
    [255] = "Colonel"
}

local rankVIP = {
    [254] = true,
    [255] = true
}
```

and then, all you need to set someone's rank label's text is this:

```lua
local rankInGroup = player:GetRankInGroup(14472135)
RankTag.Text = ranks[rankInGroup]
VIPTag.Visible = rankVIP[rankInGroup] or false
```

Here, the `or false` means "if I couldn't find this (if this is nothing, if this is *nil*), make the visibility false. If I did find something, then it will be that."

With all of the fixes and improvements, here is the new code:

```
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local Tag = ServerStorage.Tag

local ranks = {
    [1] = "Trainee",
    [2] = "Police",
    [3] = "Specialist",
    [4] = "Sergeant",
    [252] = "Corporal",
    [253] = "Major",
    [254] = "Lieutenant",
    [255] = "Colonel"
}

local rankVIP = {
    [254] = true,
    [255] = true
}

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)   
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
        local CloneTag = Tag:Clone()

        local NameTag = CloneTag.NameTag
        local RankTag = CloneTag.RankTag
        local VIPTag = CloneTag.VIPTag

        NameTag.Text = player.Name

        CloneTag.Parent = char.Head
        
        if player:IsInGroup(14472135) then
            local rankInGroup = player:GetRankInGroup(14472135)
            RankTag.Text = ranks[rankInGroup]
            VIPTag.Visible = rankVIP[rankInGroup] or false
        else
            RankTag.Text = "Immigrant"
        end
    end)
end)
```